# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component using context provider

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, react-context

For a React project, I'm using multiple context providers running GraphQL queries, providing all, or some components with my needed data. For this example, I have a BookProvider that queries all the books for a specific user.

```
export const BookProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // GraphQL query for retrieving the user-belonged books
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(gql`{
    books {
        id,
        name,
        description
    }
  }
`, {
    pollInterval: 500
  })  

  if(!data?.books) return null

  return (
    <BookContext.Provider value={data?.books}>
      {!loading && children}
    </BookContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

I made sure the query wasn't loading and is available in the `data` object. For retreiving my data, I have a dashboard component wrapped in this provider. In here, there are other components loading the corresponding data.

```
const Dashboard =  () => {
  return (
    <BookProvider>
      // More components for loading data
    </BookProvider>
  )
}
```

The data is loaded like this:

```
const { id, name } = useContext(BookContext)
```

---

In the same way, I have a `AuthenticationProvider`, wrapping the whole application.

```
export const MeQuery = gql`{ me { id, email } }`

export const AuthenticationProvider = (props) => {
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(MeQuery)

  if(loading) return null
  
  const value = {
    user: (data && data.me) || null
  }
    
  return <AuthenticationContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />
}
```

For my application routes, checking if the user is authenticated, I use a `PrivateRoute` component. The `Dashboard` component is loaded by this `PrivateRoute`.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { user } = useAuthentication()

  return user ? <Route {...rest} render={props => <Component {...props} />} /> : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login' }} />
}
```

When logging in, and setting the user object, there is no problem, however, when logging out, which is a component on the `Dashboard`, it re-directs me to the login page, but I receive the following error:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    at BookProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2869:3)
    at Dashboard
    at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:85417:29)
    at PrivateRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:4180:14)
    at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:85619:29)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:85052:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:84672:35)
    at Router
```

For logging out, I'm using the following code:

```
export function useLogout() {
  const client = useApolloClient()

  const logout = useMutation(gql`mutation Logout { logout }`, { update: async cache => { 
    cache.writeQuery({ query: MeQuery, data: { me: null }})
        
    await client.resetStore()
  }})

  return logout
}

export default useLogout
```

This gets called like `const [logout] = useLogout()`

**Questions**

- Why is this error occuring?
- How can this be fixed?
- Is it a good practice running queries in context providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give it another try ;-)

You would use `useLazyQuery` instead, that seem to allow avoiding the bug that plagues `useQuery`:

```js
const [ executeQuery, { data, loading } ] = useLazyQuery(gql`${QUERY}`);
```

And then manage the polling manually:

```js
useEffect(function managePolling() {
  const timeout = null
  const schedulePolling = () => {
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      executeQuery()
      schedulePolling()
    }, 500)
  }
  executeQuery()
  schedulePolling()
  return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
}, [executeQuery])
```

(untested code, but you get the idea)

This was suggested on the same thread (https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6209#issuecomment-676373050) so maybe you already tried it...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your graphql query hook is polling data, and this will update its internal state, or try to do so, even if the component is unmounted.

I've read similar issues [in that thread](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6209) (and it looks like a bug because `useQuery` hook should detect when component is unmounted and stop polling)

One of the solutions that seems to fit your issue, is to control the polling so that you can stop it once the component unmounts.

It would look like so:

```js
export const BookProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // GraphQL query for retrieving the user-belonged books
  const { loading, data, stopPolling, startPolling } = useQuery(gql`{
    books {
        id,
        name,
        description
    }
  }`, {fetchPolicy: "network-only"})

  React.useEffect(function managePolling() {
    startPolling(500)
    return () => stopPolling()
  })

  if(!data?.books) return null

  return (
    <BookContext.Provider value={data?.books}>
      {!loading && children}
    </BookContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Does it suppress the warning?

*Note: not sure if the `{fetchPolicy: "network-only"}` option is needed*

Comment: Unfortunately it doens't, I also tried it without the polling. It's not nessacery aswell

Comment: What version of apollo client are you using?

Comment: `^3.3.12`. Thanks for the effor though.